# Opening Skype, Opera, OpenOffice logs me off

Tags: 10.10, skype, opera

Whats common among Skype, Opera, OpenOffice in Ubuntu ? Whenever I open these applications I get logged off and shows back me the login screen. This started happening since the 10.10 upgrade.

Forgot to mention :

1. Yes, its x64.
2. Each time I open these applications, the UI shows and *then* crashes.

I started each app & logged the last few lines of /var/log/syslog after each crash. Looks like something to do with sound drivers ?

**Opera :**

```
Jan  8 09:33:20 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11532]: pid.c: Daemon already running.
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_avail_delay() returned strange values: delay 0 is less than avail 8.
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   stream       : CAPTURE
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88192
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44096
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 999909
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87310
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA Intel' device 0 subdevice 0
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   stream       : CAPTURE
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88192
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44096
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 999909
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87310
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 87320
Jan  8 09:33:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[11429]: alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 87320
Jan  8 09:33:22 al-ubuntu kernel: [ 4962.078306] opera[11036]: segfault at 261 ip 0000000000000261 sp 00007fffed7cd9a8 error 14 in opera[400000+122b000]
anjanesh@al-ubuntu:~$
```

**Skype**

```
Jan  8 09:40:21 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12602]: pid.c: Daemon already running.
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_avail_delay() returned strange values: delay 0 is less than avail 8.
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   stream       : CAPTURE
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88192
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44096
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 999909
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87310
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA Intel' device 0 subdevice 0
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   stream       : CAPTURE
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88192
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44096
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 999909
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87310
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 87312
Jan  8 09:40:23 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[12485]: alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 87312
anjanesh@al-ubuntu:~$
```

**Open Office**

```
Jan  8 09:43:46 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13157]: pid.c: Daemon already running.
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_avail_delay() returned strange values: delay 0 is less than avail 16.
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   stream       : CAPTURE
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88192
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44096
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 999909
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87310
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA Intel' device 0 subdevice 0
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   stream       : CAPTURE
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 88192
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 44096
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 999909
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 87310
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 6205960286516543488
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 87320
Jan  8 09:43:48 al-ubuntu pulseaudio[13064]: alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 87320
anjanesh@al-ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: I have a similar problem - but only with Skype, and it's random.

Comment: I don't have this problem....maybe it's peculiar to x64?

Comment: Maybe your x-server crashes and restarts. Did you have a look at /var/log/syslog ?

Comment: Some apps may not have been upgraded (Java?). Check your sources.

Comment: Ive added the logs here : looks like the sound drivers are crashing them ?

Comment: Please also add the content of `~/.xsession-errors` (use http://pastebin.ubuntu.com and link it here).

Comment: the x-server crashes and restarts - what we need to find is the why.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

When you are presented with the login screen, it means your X-session crashed. You should investigate your logging, maybe it is a conflict with another package.

Comment: should be a comment, doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this situiation on Ubuntu 10.04 x64.

1. Fresh installation of Ubuntu
2. Nvidia X-driver through Ubuntu Software Center
3. Opera and Skype through Ubuntu Software Center

And after that Ubuntu began to log me out right after accepting licension agreement in Skype and Opera.

I went to `System->Administration->Update Manager` and did a full update, then reboot and everything works ok now!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the fix for this from a bug report. If you have "xfs" installed (I think it's some kind of xfont server or something), you need to remove it.

Removing that package eliminated the problem completely for me.